# Filter Datatable through date-range in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, jdbc, primefaces

I am using JSF 2.0 and primefaces 3.5, i have generated a datatable, it has a date column in it, i want to have filter the datatable by using a date range means two calendar one of which will be starting date and second will represent the ending date, my code is given below;

```
<p:datatable id="dTable" value="#{bean.list}" var="row">
  <p:column header="Name">
       #{row.names}
  </column>
  <p:column header="Date of Birth">
       #{row.dob}
  </column>
</datatable>
```

My java classes are

```
public class stud{
    public String Names;
    public Date dob;

    {getter and setter for Name and dob}
}
```

my bean class is

```
public class bean{
    private List<stud> list;
    public List<stud> getList() {
    try {
        list = new ArrayList<stud>();
        Connection con = Dbase.connect();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from students");
        while (rs.next()) {
            stud st = new stud();
            st.setNames(rs.getString(1));
            st.setDob(rs.getDate(2));
            list.add(st);
        }
        return list;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

kindly guide me how can i solve this issue. your guidance will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated (according with comments):

```
<!-- outside from dtable -->
<p:calendar widgetVar="var1" id="dtFrom" value="#{bean.dateFrom}"
    pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" mode="popup" showOn="button">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{bean.dateFilter}" update="dTable"/>
</p:calendar>

<p:calendar widgetVar="var2" id="dtTo" value="#{bean.dateTo}"
    pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" mode="popup" showOn="button" >
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{bean.dateFilter}" update="dTable"/>
</p:calendar>
<!-- datatable code -->
<!-- keep in your datatable this column according with your location -->    
<p:column id="dateColumn" headerText="Date of Birth" >
  <h:outputText value="#{row.dob}" >
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" locale="es_PE" timeZone="EST"/>
  </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

You need to add those properties in your managed-bean:

```
private Date dateFrom;
private Date dateTo;
//getters and setters
//You shouldn't put logic in your getList(), just return the list. Add your logic
// in dateFilter method and compare dateFrom and dateTo against st.getDob
```

If you need to keep your logic in getList() then delete the listeners from p:calendar and keep the date's comparison.

Comment: thanx danRod, but my problem is i want to add two calander input to the top or bottom of table so that i can give a date-range to it like for example dob from 01-01-2000 to 01-01-2005

Comment: @WiXXeY Is it like one (date) column with two (date) headers then? Don't you think it is better to take both date filters out of datatable? (then you can update your datatable using each date filter with ajax)

Comment: well it would be better but can u guide me how can i do this??